# Custom UIView: Xcode nullability warnings for overrides of initWithFrame and initWithCoder methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am implementing a custom `UIView` and would like to override both initializers from `UIView`, so I copied their declarations exactly as they appear in `UIView.h` to my `CustomUIView.h`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

But during the build, Xcode shows warnings for both of these lines, respectively:

> CustomUIView.h:13:4: Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier
>   (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)
>   CustomUIView.h:14:49: Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable,
>   or _Null_unspecified)

Why I'm getting those warnings, if the declarations are taken from the Cocoa framework sources and how to fix them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Throughout the Cocoa `.h` files, there are `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` macros usages in the beginning and the end respectively, which make all pointers as `nonnull` in method declarations not marked explicitly with the nullability annotations (either `nonnull` or `nullable`).

After adding these macros to my `CustomUIView.h`, XCode warnings are gone:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CustomUIView : UILabel

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```